# .htaccess without matching ifmodule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, webserver

I am trying to deploy a laravel api with apache, but I am constant getting "internal server error".In errorlog, error is defined with "C:/Apache24/htdocs/ErenA/public/.htaccess:  without matching  section". I tried changing .htaccess file, delete the ifmodule element in httpd.conf and keeping only "directory index index.html index.php" but nothing seems to working

so here is my .htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And Also I will add httpd.conf ifModule:

```
   <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    </IfModule>
```

All AllowOverride is All and require all is granted in config file.
Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 `IfModule` closing (`</IfModule>`), but only 1 opens `<IfModule dir_module>`

So your content should be like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

See that I have removed the middle `</IfModule>` and because you continue using `Rewrite` module (`RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`), I just put those inside...

Comment: so this almost solved my problem, but it can not access to my public folder now. When I try to open something inside my public folder, it gives an internal server error. I am new to apache, What can be the problem?

Comment: You need to check the logs, if you are using laravel, check those. Internal server error could literally be ANYTHING, so check logs please